# Can i use Cakephp 2 with mysql without using PDO?

Tags: mysql, pdo, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to host a cakephp2 application on an old managed server that has pdo_mysql disabled. Politics dictates that I'm unable to rectify this problem, so I'm looking for connection alternatives.

cakephp is producing the following error:
"A Database connection using "Mysql" was missing or unable to connect.
The database server returned this error: Selected driver is not enabled"

Is there a way to connect to the database using the older mysql database extension?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do it.

If you want to, you could write your own DboSource class, you could reuse the the [existing one](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Mysql.html) and use the old-deprecated mysql database extension. (Or if you're lucky you could find one on the internet, but i doubt it)

Then you'll only need to change the DboSource in your settings to use your own class

Hope this helps